# How to install win7, xp and linux triple boot on Ssd?

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows-xp

i would also like win7 to boot up as default from the grub menu first, and then from windows menu itself also, so that it would always come up after a reboot...

and probably give win7 and xp the same separate partition to share stuff between them, and all necessary boot, root, home and swap partitions for linux (lmde4, so which filesystems should those be... and was swap supposed to be the first or last partition then...)

Comment: That seems like a complicated way to do things. Get a Windows 10 Pro 64-bit machine, install VMware Workstation or Hyper-V and install Windows 7 and Linux as guests. If you really need XP, get VMware Workstation. I have Windows 7, Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000, Windows NT4 workstation, older Windows, Kali and Ubuntu all here as guests on my host Windows 10 machine. I can share files real time between guests and host.

Comment: some ports wont work over Vm, so i still need the triple option..

Comment: Triple boot is complicated and in a good machine, all ports work. My ports all work fine. I do not have 15 or 20 minutes to save, close, exit, change systems, open documents every time I want something different. By all means follow your own instincts, but i like my life smooth

Comment: well, the only point of upgrade is progress, so it would be kinda nice to pimp up the machine a bit, but some special apps still wont work over Vm (certain ports needed)